# Fitting a solution of a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: fitting

I have this system of 5 equations and 5 unknowns where the lowercase letters are variables and the uppercase letters are adjustable parameters.  This system of equations can only be approximated by NSolve.  Then I make a list of `Log10[x/(1-x)]` and plot that vs Ee.

I would like to fit this plot of `Log10[x/(1-x)]` vs Ee to the line defined by the points: `{{0.5, 0}, {0.7, 0.3}}` by adjusting a, b, c, and d.  How can this be done?

```
Log10[x/(1 - x)] == a + y 
z == b w
z + v == c y 
Ee == w + y
v == d x

eqns = {x4, x5, x6, x8, x9}

vars = {x, y, z, w, v};

(* Makes a table of solutions for values of Ee that vary from 0.3 to 0.7 *)
sols[evalue_] := NSolve[eqns /. Ee -> evalue, vars, Reals] 
sollist = Table[sols[Ee], {Ee, 0.3, 0.7, 0.05}]

(* Compiles a list of log10[x/(1-x)] *)
masterlist = {}
Do[logx1x[sollist[[i, 1]]], {i, 9}]
```

.

```
logx1x = Function[singlesol,
frac = singlesol[[1, 2]];
frac = N[Log10[frac/(1 - frac)]];
Print[frac];
AppendTo[masterlist, frac]
]
```

Comment: It's a good idea to only use names beginning with a lowercase letter for variables, as uppercase letters may very well collide with internally defined and protected (not overwritable) symbols, famous examples being `D` and `N`. It's best to just avoid them in general.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was using a lowercase d in my real code but changed it to make it look pretty in the question without noticing.  Let me fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets work a little bit with your question.

You have five equations.

```
Log10[x/(1 - x)] == a + y
z == b w
v + z == c y
evalue == w + y
v == d x
```

and you want to treat `x`, `y`, `z`, `v` and `w` as variables and `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as parameters.

To start let's use the five equations to eliminate four of the variables.

```
Eliminate[{
  Log10[x/(1 - x)] == a + y,
  z == b w,
  v + z == c y,
  evalue == w + y,
  v == d x
  },
 {v, w, y, z}
 ]

(* -a b Log[10] - a c Log[10] - d x Log[10] + 
  b Log[x/(1 - x)] + c Log[x/(1 - x)] == b evalue Log[10] *)
```

Now we are left with one equation and four parameters.

This should cause a warning flag to go off. With only one equation and two data points, there will be an infinite number of parameters that will make it fit.

Since the input is written in terms of `x` and the output in terms of `evalue`, let's solve the above equation for `evalue`.

```
Solve[-a b Log[10] - a c Log[10] - d x Log[10] + 
   b Log[x/(1 - x)] + c Log[x/(1 - x)] == b evalue Log[10], evalue]

(* {{evalue -> (-a b Log[10] - a c Log[10] - d x Log[10] + 
    b Log[x/(1 - x)] + c Log[x/(1 - x)])/(b Log[10])}} *)
```

Hopefully by studying this equation one sees that we can eliminate at least the product of `b Log[10]` by grouping it with the other parameters.

I will rename `c/b` as `cb` and `d/b` as `db`. This reduces it to three parameters and the model can be written as:

```
 evalue == (1 + cb) Log10[x/(1 - x)] - a (1 + cb) - db x
```

You have two data points `{Log10[x/(1 - x)], evalue}` represented as `{0.5, 0}` and `{0.7, 0.3}`.

The corresponding `x` values are:

```
Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E])
E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10))
```

We can run `NonlinearModelFit` to determine the parameters

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[{{Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), 0},
       {E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), 0.3}},
       (1 + cb) Log10[x/(1 - x)] - a (1 + cb) - db x,
       {a, cb, db}, x]
```

Realize that with two data points and three parameters there are an infinite number of points that will fit.

The results are:

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 0.250341, cb -> 2.35956, db -> -0.179157} *)
```

We can check it by evaluating it at the two input points.

```
nlm[Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E])]
(* 7.87744*10^-10 *)
```

and

```
nlm[E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10))]
(* 0.3 *)
```

You really need at least two more data points in order to say anything meaningful about the parameters `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

### Update - six data points

Now three groups of two data points `{x, evalue}` are provided.

The first group is the original and it is associated with the parameter `a`.

The second group is associated with the parameter `a` reduced by one.

The third group is associated with the parameter `a` reduced by two.

We construct `data` where the first column is the group id, the second column is the `x` value and the last column is `evalue`. It is shown below:

```
data = {{"a0", Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), 0}, {"a0", E^(7/10)/(
    1 + E^(7/10)), 0.3}, {"a1", Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), -0.5}, {"a1", 
    E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), -0.2}, {"a2", Sqrt[E]/(
    1 + Sqrt[E]), -1}, {"a2", E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), -0.7}};

Grid[data, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We need to revert to the original equation after eliminate the four variables but retaining all the parameters, namely:

```
(-a b Log[10] - a c Log[10] - d x Log[10] + b Log[x/(1 - x)] + 
   c Log[x/(1 - x)])/(b Log[10])
```

The strategy will be to build a function that reconstructs `evalue` but depending upon the group will use either `a`, `a-1` or `a-2`.

That function looks like this:

```
modelFun[id_, x_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[
  {
   aNew = Switch[id,
     "a0",
     a,
     "a1",
     a - 1,
     "a2",
     a - 2
     ]
   },
  (-aNew b Log[10] - aNew c Log[10] - d x Log[10] + b Log[x/(1 - x)] +
    c Log[x/(1 - x)])/(b Log[10])
  ]
```

Now use this in `NonlinearModelFit`. Note that there are two input variables, the group id and `x` coordinate.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, modelFun[id, x, a, b, c, d],
    {a, b, c, d}, {id, x}]
```

The parameters are

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> -9.13243, b -> 1.73175, c -> -2.59763, d -> -13.0058} *)
```

and the function is

```
Normal[nlm]
(* 0.250783 (29.9469 x - 0.865875 Log[x/(1 - x)] + 
   1.99375 Switch[id,
     "a0", -9.13243,
     "a1", -9.13243 - 1,
     "a2", -9.13243 - 2]) *)
```

Let's validate that it works correctly.

We will see if the reconstructed `evalue` matches the `evalue` from the data.

```
Table[Module[
  {
   id = dataRow[[1]],
   x = dataRow[[2]],
   evalue = dataRow[[3]],
   evalueRec
   },
  evalueRec = nlm[id, x];
  {id, x, evalue, evalueRec}
  ],
 {dataRow, data}
 ]

(* {{"a0", Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), 0, 8.90962*10^-16},
    {"a0", E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), 0.3, 0.3},
    {"a1", Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), -0.5, -0.5},
    {"a1", E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), -0.2, -0.2},
    {"a2", Sqrt[E]/(1 + Sqrt[E]), -1, -1.},
    {"a2", E^(7/10)/(1 + E^(7/10)), -0.7, -0.7}} *)
```

Works fine.

However, big warning. The correlation matrix shows a high degree of correlation between the parameters.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is entirely due to the data. More data points and in particular a greater number of `x` values would reduce the correlation and produce more robust parametes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (happy thanksgiving), but thank you for this general solution.  There are more data points, actually.  When A is decreased by 2, the plot should roughly fit the points {{0.5, -1},{0.7,-0.7}}.  Does this help at all?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69389/discussion-on-answer-by-jack-lavigne-fitting-a-solution-of-a-nonlinear-system-of).

Comment: How do I use this nlm[id,x] function?  If I type `nlm[1,0.1]` then I just get 
`1.22814 + 
   1.99375 Switch[1,
     "a0", -9.13243,
     "a1", -9.13243 - 1,
     "a2", -9.13243 - 2])`.
I was hoping I'd get a specific value for evalue from this.

Comment: You need to feed nlm two arguments where the first is the id which is a string, either "a0", "a1" or "a2". The second argument is the x-value.

Comment: This code will plot the results. `Show[
 Plot[nlm["a0", x], {x, 0.622459, 0.66818}, PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotRange -> {{0.6, 0.7}, {-1, 0.35}}],
 Plot[nlm["a1", x], {x, 0.622459, 0.66818}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[nlm["a2", x], {x, 0.622459, 0.66818}, 
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0]],
 ListPlot[data[[1 ;; 2, {2, 3}]], 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Black}],
 ListPlot[data[[3 ;; 4, {2, 3}]], 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Black}],
 ListPlot[data[[5 ;; 6, {2, 3}]], 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Black}]
 ]`